# How to prevent user adding a Lead to a Cadence? [Salesforce]

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to prevent users to add Leads with status 'Do not Contact' to Cadence.
I want to give an error message to the user and do not allow adding these Leads to Cadences.
How can I achieve that?

I can not add apex trigger to give error because it says only LWC supports that.